# "'CDVPlugin.h' file not found" in Cordova as component (Cleaver)

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I added Cordova as a component to my iOS project. Adding a custom plugin leads to the error, despite that the plugin works in a Cordova-only project:

```
'CDVPlugin.h' file not found
```

- PhoneGap / Cordova 1.7.0 installed
- Checked multiple times to correctly implement the steps https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-ios/blob/master/guides/How%20to%20Use%20Cordova%20as%20a%20Component.md ("Adding Cleaver to your Xcode project (CordovaLib sub-project)")
- The Plugin works in a plain cordova-based application (Cordova Xcode template)
- Adding "-all_load" to the 'other linker flags' in the main project does have no effect

The problematic part is as follows:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#ifdef CORDOVA_FRAMEWORK
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>
#else
#import "CDVPlugin.h"
#endif
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 57):

For xcode7 add `"$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include"` to your **Header Search Paths** (and you may need to set **Enable Bitcode** to **No** - was necessary for me, but may be related to different problem with xc7)

Comment: Right on time! this is the correct answer. Thank you Kind Sir!

Comment: Just adding "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include" to my Header Search Paths solves the issue in my case. Enable Bitcode remains to YES. To be noted the issue is appeared after an update of Xcode from a previous version 7 to Version 7.1 (7B91b)

Comment: As @Lisarien said, it's not necesary to enable BitCode. Just adding the right path do the job ! It's worked for me !

Comment: you made my day sir! Thank you!

Comment: No works for me, my bit code NO and string `"$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include"` too no work

Comment: This worked for me, after Enable Bitcode set to No. Thanks.

Comment: Upgrading my cordova iOS version was the solution for me.

Comment: This issue is coming back up in Xcode 8 with server 5.4, but only from an Xcode bot. Building locally still works fine.

Answer (score 24):

Click on the project icon in the Project Navigator,

select your Project, then select the "Build Settings" tab

Enter "Header Search Paths" in the search field

Add `"$(CORDOVALIB)/Classes"` and check the Recursive checkbox - for the **Header Search Paths** value

optional
Add `"-all_load"` and `"-Obj-C"` - for the **Other Linker Flags** value

see [detailed description (step 17)](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-ios/blob/master/guides/How%20to%20Use%20Cordova%20as%20a%20Component.md)

Comment: https://github.com/purplecabbage/GDCordova/blob/master/docs/How%20to%20Use%20Cordova%20as%20a%20Component.md

Answer (score 22):

Change your header file to:

`#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>`

it is working in my application.

Comment: This is the right solution for Xcode 7.1 - all the rest did not resolve it for me.

Answer (score 21):

I had this issue using Cordova.  Come to find out my CordovaLib folder under the ios platform directory vanished.

I did:

```
cordova platform remove ios
```

then

```
cordova platform add ios
```

...and this fixed the issue.

Comment: Yes yes yes. This is the solution to all of life's problems.

Comment: Several months later and i'm facing this issue again, i didn't realize i've already posted a resolution.  My own fix didn't do it for me :(

Answer (score 5):

I have spent awful lot of time trying to fix the same issue in my project, so let me share my findings. It might be relevant for those who are able to build the project in one configuration, but in another configuration (e.g. when building unit tests) precompiler fails to find `CDVPlugin.h`.

You have to make sure that `CordovaLib` sub-project has the same set of configurations as your main project.

1. Select the main project in Xcode in project navigator.
2. Click on the project icon (above the Targets).
3. Select `Info` tab.
4. Expand `Configurations`.

So, this is a set of your app configurations. In my example it looked like this:
[image: App configurations]

You need to have the same set of configurations in your `CordovaLib` sub-project.

1. Select `CordovaLib` sub-project.
2. Click on the project icon (above the Targets).
3. Select `Info` tab.
4. Expand `Configurations`.
5. Make sure you have the same set of configurations as in the main project. If some configurations are missing:

   1. Click `+` button.
   2. Select `Duplicate "Release" Configuration`
   3. Give the right name for configuration. Copy-paste it from main project settings.

Now perform a clean build.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Phonegap 2.9.1 (Nov 2013))

I encountered the same problem while trying to make an open source "C" phone gap plugin work. The solution was to add the Cordovalib.xcodeproj to the target project, once done, click on your_project.xcodeproj - you will need to look in the Target Settings, under the Build Phases Tab, make sure that Cordovalib is added in Target Dependencies.

Once done it should allow the statement:
     #import  
to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13834636/1693477):

I had the same problem while installing the ShareKit plugin on Xcode 4.5, cordova 2.1.0 & JQM 1.2.0. The problematic block was:

```
#ifdef CORDOVA_FRAMEWORK
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVPluginResult.h>
//#import <Cordova/JSONKit.h>

#else
#import "CDVPlugin.h"
#import "CDVPluginResult.h"
#import "JSONKit.h"
#endif
```

What worked for me is commenting out the #ifdef line as well as commenting out the whole #else block.

Also, the #import  line was already commented out in the source code that I downloaded with the plugin, so I didn't bother messing with that.

Might be of some help to you.

Answer (score 0):

In xcode 8 and 8 + simply commenting the line worked for me:

```
#import ...
```

This is specifically useful if you are trying to extend IOS app build using ionic or cordova to have watchkit or widget control natively.

Answer (score -1):

replace

## import

with
(

## import "Classes/CDVPlugin.h"

OR

## import "CordovaLib/Classes/CDVPlugin.h")