# 'Cordova/CDVPlugin.h' file not found in Phonegap

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I am using cordova 2.1 in my project.when i sent code to my client,he told that cordova file is missing and he downloading new 2.1 version and add that setup in that project then 'Cordova/CDVPlugin.h' file not found error is occurred.I also follwed this link ["'CDVPlugin.h' file not found" in Cordova as component (Cleaver)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714600/cdvplugin-h-file-not-found-in-cordova-as-component-cleaver).[image].Here I attached screen shot for error.

Comment: can you add that  'Cordova/CDVPlugin.m' into compile sources..

Comment: i can't add the file into compile sources.But when i add that file in compile sources same error is ocurred

Comment: then now clean the xcode and try again to build...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet that the Cordova.framework is not included in your XCode project.

[image]

To add it follow theses instructions:
- Under build Phases
- In the Link Binary With Libraries
- Click on the "+" button in the bottom
- Click on "Add Other..."
- Go in Macintosh HD -> Users -> Shared -> Cordova -> Frameworks
- Select Cordova.framework and click on Open

Try again to build your project.

Comment: I try this instruction.It's useful for me.Thanks.But same Cordova/CDVPlugin.h file not found error is occurred.

Comment: Would you be able to upgrade the project to a recent version of Cordova? It complicated to find support from the community for old versions.

Comment: Now I create new project with latest version of cordova,now its works properly.Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2):

If Cordova has been added to your project as a sub-project (as against as a framework),
check that that sub-project's target has been added to your 'Link Binary With Libraries' list in your app target's 'Build Phases'.

In simple steps:

1. Click on your project name in the Project Navigator.
2. In the project view which opens up, in the left pane, click on your target.
3. Click the 'Build Phases' tab.
4. Open the 'Link Binary With Libraries' pop-down list.
5. You should see a list of all your current frameworks here.
6. Now, if you are using Cordova in your project as a sub-project, you simply add the 'libCordova.a' to your 'Link Binary With Libraries' list ('+' button and then pick from the list under 'Workspace').
7. But if you are using Cordova as a framework, 'Cordova.framework' should also be listed here. If it's not, add it by clicking the '+' button, 'Add Other', navigating to it and adding it in.