# Cordova/CDVJSON.h file not found using plugin SQLite in IOS

Tags: ios, apache, cordova, xcode7, cordova-plugins

I have a project with **Apache Cordova** and I'am using the plugin:
https://github.com/Antair/Cordova-SQLitePlugin (A Cordova plugin to use sqlite databases, with the ability to use pre-populated, bundled databases on iOS and Android.)

My project run normally in Android, but not in IOS, Xcode show me an error :

**Cordova/CDVJSON.h file not found**

[image]

I'am using **Xcode 7.0.1**  and **Cordova 6.3.1**

Where I can find CDVJSON.h ???  or how I can import it into Xcode ???

Comment: Have you looked at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714600/cdvplugin-h-file-not-found-in-cordova-as-component-cleaver

Comment: Yes, but that solution not work for me.

Comment: Okay. I also noticed that the plugin you're using is 2 years old; the original it was forked from has been maintained pretty regularly (I use it in my project, and haven't run into the issue you're seeing). You might want to try it out: https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage.
EDIT: if you need pre-populated DB support and Windows support, check out the -ext version of the database plugin: https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext

Comment: Finally it works using: [https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) ,   to pre-populated DB I use the **sqlBatch** funcion, It works very well in Android and IOS.

Comment: Awesome! Good to hear that it works.